# why the address difference is getting printed (according to the pointer type)

Tags: c, pointers, increment

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int *p=0;
    char *ch=0;
    p++;
    ch++;
    printf ("%d and %d\n",p,ch);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
4 and 1
```

1. I know the char pointer increments as +1 in the address that it is pointing too.
2. I know the pointer to an int increments as +4 in the address in gcc  that it is pointing too.
3. I know Derefrencing a pointer should be done by the use of * with the pointer.

Queries:

1. Why is this not giving any garbage value for p and ch as both are pointers and has not assigned any address;
2. Why is this giving me the address difference that the respective pointer has obtained while incrementing, or is **this a undefined behavior**.

3.**Why is the output 4 and 1?**

Pl. Explain.

I have compiled this code on gcc-4.3.4.
Its a C code.
I am sorry if this comes out to be a copy of some question as I was not able to find any such question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your code is printing pointers as integers. While this is probably what you're trying to do, it is not defined behavior, as it is entirely unportable on platforms where the size of a pointer (in bytes) is not the same as the size of `int`. if you want to print pointer values, use `%p` instead.

To answer your questions. You *are* assigning values to *both* pointers: **0**, which is synonymous with **NULL**.

Second. The reason you're getting 4 1 is due to the size of an `int` vs the size of a `char` on your platform. The char is going to be 1. On your platform, an`int` is 4 bytes wide. When incrementing a pointer the compiler will automatically move the address it references by the byte-count of the underlying type it represents.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int *p=0;    // int is 4 bytes on your platform
    char *ch=0;  // char is 1 byte
    p++;         // increments the address in p by 4
    ch++;        // increments the address in ch by 1
    printf ("%d  and %d\n",p,ch);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: you're going to get the similar results, but with a supported print statement, do this instead:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int *p=0;
    char *ch=0;
    p++;
    ch++;
    printf ("%p and %p\n",p,ch);
    return 0;
}
```

Output (on my Mac) is:

```
0x4 and 0x1
```

Comment: So it is not a undefined behaviour. It will give me the same output according to the size of pointer, int and char on different machine.

Comment: @tapasweni You need to read that again. **Using `printf()` with a "%d" format specifier and a pointer parameter is undefined behavior.** Incrementing pointers, even NULL ones, is certainly ***defined*** behavior.

Comment: It means the address in pointers p and ch is now 4 and 1 preceded by zero as following the rules of how address's are stored in my machine. Pl correct me if  I am wrong.

Comment: @tapasweni change the `%d` formats in your `printf()` format string to `%p` and it will be defined behavior. You're not printing integers (or chars); you're printing **addresses** (i.e. pointer values).

Comment: @tapasweni No problem. I hope it helped.

Comment: It's still undefined behavior. You **must** cast the printf arguments for `%p` to `(void *)`.

Comment: @Jens I was unaware of that. Do you have a cite for that, or is it in the general documentation for `printf()` ?

Comment: @WhozCraig The C Standard requires that `%p` must be matched with a pointer-to-void (a pointer-to-other-than-void will not do). Mismatched format specifiers are always undefined behavior.

Comment: @Jens I'm going to have to open a question on that, because I thought pointer-to-anything was a cast-free synonym to pointer-to-void, if that is in the spec, which I'll also have to go search.

Comment: @Jens Found it in the spec, in case you wanted a cited reference: C11.7.21.6.1p8, at least as of the draft I have, and I can't see it likely to change. The cite is: " **p**  The argument shall be a pointer to void. The value of the pointer is converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an implementation-defined manner."

Answer (score 3):

> 1.Why is this not giving any garbage value for p and ch as both are pointers and has not assigned any address;

err, you assigned address here > `int *p = 0` and `char *ch = 0`. `p` contains address `0x00000000` and `ch` contains the address `0x00000000`

> 2.Why is this giving me the address difference that the respective pointer has obtained while incrementing, or is this a undefined
>   behavior.

`char *ch = 0;` means that `ch` contains the address `0`. Incrementing the address using `++` will increment the value by `sizeof(char) viz 1`. Similarly for integer. `p` contains the address 0. And using the `++` operator increments the value by `sizeof(int)` which seems to be `4` on your machine(note, this isn't always true, especially for 64 bit machine).

> 3.Why this output is 4 1 ? here

Because at first, `p` contained 0, then incremented by `sizeof(type_of(p))` = `sizeof(int)` = `4` on your machine and `ch` incremented by `sizeof(type_of(ch))` = `sizeof(char)` = 1.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, I have added the answers to your questions inline:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x=0,*p=0;
    char c = 'A', *ch=0;
    x++; 

    // You have initialized this to 0, so incrementing adds 4 (int pointer)
    // Remember, the address '4' means nothing here
    p++; 

    // You have initialized this to 0, so incrementing adds 1 (char pointer)
    // Remember, the address '1' means nothing here
    ch++;

    // You are now printing the values of the pointers itself
    // This does not make any sense. If you are using pointers, you would want to know what is being referenced
    printf ("%d , %d  and %d\n",x,p,ch); 

    // This will FAIL
    // Because, you are now trying to print the data pointed by the pointers
    // Note the use of '*'. This is called de-referencing
    printf ("%d , %d  and %d\n", x, *p, *ch); 

    // Let p point to x, de-referencing will now work
    p = &x;
    printf ("%d , %d\n", x, *p); // 1, 1

    // Let ch point to c, de-referencing will now work
    ch = &c;
    printf ("%c , %c\n", c, *ch); // 'A', 'A'

    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Pl. explain why is it printing 4 1. I know I am not derefrencing the pointer. And can you Pl tell                                                in the line p = &x;
printf ("%d , %d\n", x, *p); // 4, 4 why 4,4

Comment: Because 0 + 4 = 4 and 0 + 1 = 1, and because the value of a `Type *` incremented by 1 increments the byte address that the pointer references by `sizeof(Type)` (1 unit of the size of the type, so after the increment, it points to the next value of the type).

Comment: I don't think it will print 4,4 it will print 1,1.as x=1 after increment and p has the address of x and *p will be 1. Pl. correct me if I am wrong.